# Why does the Shepherd leave the 99 sheep in a desert?

Tags: luke, parables

Luke 15:4 King James Version

> What man of you, having an hundred sheep, if he lose one of them, doth not leave the **ninety and nine** in the **wilderness**, and go after that which is lost, until he find it?

This verse is part of a larger context in which Jesus is teaching through parables to convey spiritual truths.

In the Bible, the wilderness is often used as a symbol of test, trial, loneliness, and a place of spiritual quest and reflection.

Jeremiah 4:11 - English Standard Version

> At that time it will be said to this people and to Jerusalem, “A hot wind from the bare heights in the desert toward the daughter of my people, not to winnow or cleanse,

Trial and Test: The wilderness is often associated with periods of trial and testing. Deuteronomy 8:2

Spiritual Search and Intimacy with God: The desert is also seen as a place of spiritual search. Matthew 4:1-2

Renewal and Preparation: The desert is often considered a place of spiritual renewal and preparation for a greater purpose. Isaiah 43:19

Why does the Shepherd leave the 99 sheep in a desert, which is a symbol of danger, lions, snakes and scorpions?

Comment: What do *you* think? You're capable of reading the passage, surely you might have some idea. Please [edit] this to ask a substantial question, because this is not up to the standards of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that Luke 15 records three parables about "Lost" things:

- V1-7 - The Lost **Sheep** which knew it was lost but could not find its way back
- V8-10 - The Lost **Coin** which did not know it was lost and could not find its way back
- The Lost **Son** - who knew he was lost and knew his way home, and ultimately was drawn home by the Father's grace

In the case of the lost sheep, the explanation of this parable is given in V7 -

> In the same way, I tell you that there will be more joy in heaven over
> one sinner who repents than over ninety-nine righteous ones who do not
> need to repent.

This essentially states the meaning of the elements of the parable

- sheep represent people, whether lost or saved
- the 99 sheep represent people who do not need to repent, ie, who are already saved
- the lost sheep represents a person who needs to repent and to be saved

Now, recall that this is a parable, some of whose elements are added for dramatic and narrative effect and do not necessarily correspond to reality.  The fact that the shepherd (representing Jesus who left heaven to come and die for sinners) left the 99 in the desert, does NOT mean that the 99 sheep were bereft during the search because:

- Heb 13:5 - Keep your lives free from the love of money and be content with what you have, for God has said: “Never will I leave you, never will I forsake you.”
- Matt 28:20 - ... And surely I am with you always, even to the end of the age.”

Thus, in the parable, the shepherd's departure to find the lost sheep does NOT mean that others are abandoned.  It simply means that heaven expends every effort to find the lost sinner.

Comment: "the 99 sheep represent people who do not need to repent, ie, who are already saved" Does this refer to the 99 righteous people who need no repentance? Luke 15:7

Comment: @Betho's - correct - as per Jesus' own words.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, in Matthew's version of the parable (Mt. 18:24ff) the shepherd leaves the flock in the mountains not the wilderness. But the message is the same: The ones who remain with the flock are in far less danger than the one who has gotten lost.

Another difference between Matthew's context and Luke's is that in Luke, the parable serves as a lesson to the scribes and Pharisees who criticized Jesus for eating with tax collectors and sinners. In Matthew it is a lesson in humility to the disciples, who have been wondering about who is greatest in the kingdom of heaven.

In Luke, Jesus needs to minister to those who have gone off the path of righteousness, while those who already walk in God's way do not need rescue.  In Matthew, it is the disciples who must care for the lost sheep: they must care for the "little ones" who believe in Jesus. In Luke, the parable closes with "I tell you... there will be more joy in heaven over one sinner who repents than over ninety-nine righteous people who don’t need repentance." In Matthew, it closes with "It is not the will of your Father in heaven that even one of these little ones perish."

Thus, in Luke, the lost sheep represents a sinner who has gone astray from righteousness; but in Matthew it represents a vulnerable believer who must be cared for by the disciples. Be that as it may, in both cases the shepherd is willing to leave the flock to find the lost sheep because that sheep is in immediate mortal danger. The other sheep are relatively safe.

Comment: This word αφησει has a connotation of "abandon" in Strong's dictionary, although this dictionary is very outdated (G863), however, it also allows your vision.

Comment: Is the Mt. 18:24ff reference correct?

Answer (score 1):

Luke 15:7 says, "*I tell you that in the same way there will be more rejoicing in heaven over one sinner who repents than over ninety-nine righteous persons **who do not need to repent**.*". In Jesus' teaching, is there anyone 'who do not need to repent'?

In John 8:7, when a group of people were about to stone a woman caught in adultery, Jesus said, *“Let any one of you who is without sin be the first to throw a stone at her.”* This statement implies that no one is without sin. However, most of the Pharisees and the teachers of the law may not see it this way.

In Matthew 23:13-36, Jesus gave seven woes to the Pharisees and the teachers of the law, condemning their self-righteous hypocrisy because it blinded them from seeing their need for repentance and a Savior. Jesus told them in John 9:41, *"If you were blind, you would not be guilty of sin; but now that you claim you can see, your guilt remains."*

Therefore, the ninety-nine righteous persons who do not need to repent in Matthew 15:7, is likely a satire to the Pharisees and the teachers of the law who despised the tax collectors as described in Matthew 15:1-2. These ninety-nine sheep were left in the open country, signified the fate they might receive if not turning from their sin.

Answer (score 0):

The Greek word ἐρήμῳ can have a broader meaning than just "desert." In classical and biblical Greek, it often refers to a desolate, uninhabited place, which can include deserts but also encompasses other types of sparsely populated terrain like plains or wilderness areas.

As for an example of a Greek word for "peace" from the same root, the term "ἐρημία" (eremia) comes to mind. This word, derived from the same root as ἐρήμῳ, can mean solitude or a state of being alone, which can be conceptually linked to peace in the sense of a tranquil, undisturbed state.